# Perl Excel Modules - using scalar values

Tags: perl, excel, excel-formula, perl-module

Using the Perl Spreadsheet::ParseExcel Module and the Perl Spreadsheet::WriteExcel Module, I am trying to assign a scalar value for a cell with a list value, IF the cell is not blank. The purpose of this is to assign a value of 1 to a cell with a list value present, so that I may add a number of columns together to have a new column with the sum of that row.

For example:

```
      A    B    C      D   E(Sum Column)
```

Row2  Science  Math    History   Drama     4

---

Row3  Math   blank           Science   blank          2

---

Row4  History  Science  English     blank        3

---

So, if the cell is not blank or "", it is assigned a value of 1, and if it is blank it is given a value of 0.

How would I go about something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit an existing Excel spreadsheet with those modules, other than by using [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel%3a%3aSaveParser)

Alternatively, it may be easier to read in the whole spreadsheet using ParseExcel, calculate the sum (by the scalar value of a `grep` on the row values), and output a new XLS file using WriteExcel